# Key binding. How to run a external script (external command/program) in sublime text 2 when pressing a key?

Tags: keyboard, exec, shortcut, sublimetext2

I would like to run a external python script (or external command/program) when I press a key on Sublime Text 2.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a [solution](http://sapiensgarou.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/1-preferences-bindings-user-2-override.html):

**Preferences->Key Bindings - User** and put this in the file (overriding the `[`,`]` inside):

```
[
    { "keys": ["<your shortucut>"], "command": "exec", "args": { "cmd": ["<path to your script>"]} }
]
```

Where `<your shortcut>` as the name says is the shortcut (examples: <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>**+**<kbd>shift</kbd>**+**<kbd>F1</kbd>, etc.) and `<path to your command>` is the location of your command (examples: `echo`, `/home/user/scripts/my_script.py`, `ls`, etc.)

Comment: @Maslow just add more quoted values. Example: [ { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "exec", "args": { "cmd": ["touch", "test.txt"]} } ]

Comment: I get "[Errno 8] Exec format error" while doing this in sublime text 3. The same script file runs fine on terminal. !!

Comment: Sublime 3 requires the `F` to be lowercase... weird (yes i know this is for sublime 2, but just incase anyone was having issues :P)

Comment: This does not seems to work with variables like $project_path.